# Setup private docker registry with OAUauthentication (with specific namespace for each user)

Tags: authentication, docker, oauth-2.0, docker-registry

My use case requires to setup a private docker registry with the ability to authenticate users to **specific namespaces** whereas prevent from authenticated users to pull/push images to other namespaces than the ones assigned to them.

So far my investigation points me to a setup with the following modules

- docker registry (of course)
- Oauth2 authentication module, with scope per user
- setup oauth on registry [config.yml](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#/auth) file

Is this type of setup possible? How can I configure docker registry to use an OAuth2 server? I have found the following resources from the official documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/

In my config.yml I have added the following lines:

```
auth:
  token:
    realm: http://localhost:8200/oauth/token
    issuer: Auth Service
    service: Docker Registry
    rootcertbundle: /certs/server.crt
```

In location `http://localhost:8200/` is my QAuth2 implementation, which is based on Spring OAuth2

when I attempt to login to my registry

```
$> docker login -u admin -p admin  https://localhost:5000
```

It seems that none of the flows of QAuth2 is followed by docker, I notice that it sends a GET (which is not allowed but I kind of hack it to pass) request with the following form:

```
/oauth/token?account=admin&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=Docker+Registry
```

The login and password are in the authorization header and The Oauth2 server does a basic authentication with success but then it misses grant_type, username, password for password flow etc.

What am I doing wrong?

A proper OAuth2 token request as far as I know for example with the password flow has the following form:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:8200/oauth/token" \ 
-d "username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&" \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \ 
-H "Accept: application/json" \ 
-H "Authorization: Basic ZG9ja2VyOmRvY2tlcg=="
```

(where in the Authorization header is the clien_id:client_secret which is allowed to do the specific password flow in base64 in my case docker:docker)

Is there any working example with OAuth2 and docker? I found the following example `https://github.com/opendns/registry-oauth-server` but this is a custom OAuth2 like implementation with JWT (correct me if I'm wrong) based on [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/oauth/) .

Comment: any news since 2016?